# How to get only column names of data frame that are starting with particular characters?

Tags: r, dataframe, data-manipulation

This is my code which creates dataframe and print all column names:

```
df<-data.frame("Sp1"=1:6,"Sp2"=7:12,"Sp3"=13:18, "Dp1"=1:6)
colnames(df)
```

output:

> [1] "Sp1" "Sp2" "Sp3" "Dp1"

Now I need to get only column names that are starting with `Sp`, so result should look like `"Sp1" "Sp2" "Sp3"`. How to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use regular expressions

```r
grep("^Sp",colnames(df), value = TRUE)
```

Where `^` indicates the start of the string

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr`:

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>%
  select(starts_with("Sp"))
names(df)
# [1] "Sp1" "Sp2" "Sp3"
```

If you just want to get names printed then use:

```
names(df %>%
  select(starts_with("Sp")))
#[1] "Sp1" "Sp2" "Sp3"
```